# Bootstrap menu not responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

My page is not responsive and the bootstrap menu is not working when the size is increased or decreased. The page itself is not responsive and the menu does not not work. Please help me as soon as possible the basic of the layout was taken from legalized theme from theme forest but I have not worked in wordpress.

Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html"">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='page-css'  href='css/page.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='slider-css'  href='css/slider.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css-css'  href='css/bootstrap.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-responsive-css-css'  href='css/bootstrap-responsive.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='main_style-css'  href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--
<link rel='stylesheet' id='Merriweather-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather%3A400%2C700%2C900%2C300&#038;ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css'  href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css?ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='google_fonts-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family&#038;ver=3.5.1' type='text/css' media='all' /> -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url(''); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: top left; background-attachment: fixed; }
</style>

</head>

<body class="home blog custom-background">


<div id="container">
    <div class="container-narrow">

        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <div class="top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <!-- Logo -->
                            <div class="logo" style="margin-top:35px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;">
                                                                <a href="Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited.html"><img src="img/logo4.png" alt='Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited' title="Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited"/></a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Site description -->
                            <h2 class="site_heading">Handling Money........   With Devotion And Care</h2>
                            <!-- Contact -->
                                                                                        <div class="header_contact rounded">
                                                                            <div class="phone"><img src="img/phoneicon.png" alt="phone icon" /><span>044-30228855                </span></div>
                                                                                                                <div class="email"><img src="img/mailicon.png" alt="mail icon" /><span><a href="office@vijayhemant.in">office@vijayhemant.in</a></span></div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       <div> <img src="img/separator.png" style="margin-top: -60px; width:755px;
margin-left: 390px; "></div>

<!-- Menu Navigation -->
            <div class="menu_wrap" style="position:relative; top:-60px;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-relative-top">
                      <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="container">
                          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </a>
                          <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">


<ul id="menu-menu" class="nav">
<li id="menu-item-284" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home active menu-item-284"><a title="Home" href="Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited.html">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Blog" href="commercial-vehicles.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Business<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ">
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68"><a title="Commercial Vehicles" href="commercial-vehicles.html">Commercial Vehicles</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a title="Car / LMV" href="carfinance.html">Car Finance</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-594" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-594"><a title="About Us" href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>

</li>
<li id="menu-item-275" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275"><a title="CSR" href="csr.html">CSR</a></li>

</li>
<li id="menu-item-594" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-594"><a title="Investment" href="investment.html">Investment</a></li>

<!-- <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85 dropdown-submenu"><a title="Shortcodes" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle">services<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ">
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68"><a title="Blog Fullwidth" href="">Fixed Deposits</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a title="Blog Sidebar Left" href="">Recurring Deposits</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-149"><a title="Standard" href="">Annual Reports</a></li>
</ul>
</li> -->

<li id="menu-item-594" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-594"><a title="Contact Us" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-594" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-594"><a title="Downloads" href="download.html">Downloads</a></li>
</ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>     



</header>
<section style="margin-top:-75px;">
  <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
    <div id="slider2_container" style="position: relative; width: 600px;
        height: 350px;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block;  no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 372px;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="img/slider1.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="img/slider2.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a u=image href="#"><img src="img/slider3.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 -->

        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="position: absolute; bottom: 30px; left: 620px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->

        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">slideshow</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->

</section>
 <!-- SLIDER ends -->


<!-- CONTENT STARTS -->
<section  style="height:450px;">
<div class="container">
<!--part-1-->
<div class="row-fluid part_home">

<!-- SERVICES LEFT -->
<section>

        <div class="span4 ca-menu left">
            <div class="row-fluid">

                <style type="text/css">
                    .ca-menu .ca-item270:hover {background-color: #FFFFFF}
                    .ca-menu.left .ca-item:hover a.more_link span, .ca-menu.left .ca-item:hover h1, .ca-menu.left .ca-item:hover p{color: #515151 !important;}

                    .ca-menu .ca-item270 {background-color: #D25555}                    
                    .ca-item270 .ca-main {color: #FFFFFF;}
                    .ca-item270 .ca-sub {color: #FFFFFF}
                    .ca-item270 .more_link {color: #FFFFFF;}
                </style>


                <div class="ca-item ca-item270 rounded">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                    <a href="investment.html">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Secure Future</h2>
                            <p class="ca-sub">Become an entrepreneur and grow with booming and extremely lucrative in logistic sector. We are serving in this segment since 1985 and have turned many dreams into reality.</p>
                     </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                            </div>
        </div>

<!-- SERVICES CENTER -->      


        <div class="span4 ca-menu center">          
            <div class="row-fluid">             


                <style type="text/css">
                    .ca-menu .ca-item277:hover {background-color: #FFFFFF}
                    .ca-menu.center .ca-item:hover a.more_link span, .ca-menu.center .ca-item:hover h1, .ca-menu.center .ca-item:hover p{color: #515151 !important;}
                    .ca-menu .ca-item277 {background-color: #515151}
                    .ca-item277 .ca-main {color: #FFFFFF;}
                    .ca-item277 .ca-sub {color: #FFFFFF}
                    .ca-item277 .more_link {color: #FFFFFF;}
                </style>


                <div class="ca-item ca-item277  rounded">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                    <a href="about-us.html">
                        <h2 class="ca-main">Strong Values </h2>
                        <p class="ca-sub">We value people, culture, tradition, and respect honesty, truth, integrity and experience.</p>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div><!-- span4 -->

<!-- SERVICES RIGHT -->     


        <div class="span4 ca-menu right">
            <div class="row-fluid">


                <style type="text/css">
                    .ca-menu .ca-item279:hover {background-color: #FFFFFF}
                    .ca-menu.right .ca-item:hover a.more_link span, .ca-menu.right .ca-item:hover h1, .ca-menu.right .ca-item:hover p{color: #103042 !important;}

                    .ca-menu .ca-item279 {background-color: #236890}                    
                    .ca-item279 .ca-main {color: #FFFFFF;}
                    .ca-item279 .ca-sub {color: #FFFFFF}
                    .ca-item279 .more_link {color: #FFFFFF;}
                </style>


                <div class="ca-item ca-item279 rounded">
                <a href="commercial-vehicles.html">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                    <a href="commercial-vehicles.html">
                            <h2 class="ca-main"> Dedicated Services </h2>
                            <p class="ca-sub">  We have a bunch of loyal associates who have grown the company and will partner you in all your needs.</p>
                         </a>
                         </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
             </div>
        </div><!-- span4 -->

  <ul>
<li> We are entering our 30th Year of Service.
<li> Loans to operations from 1year to 3years upto 70% value of the vehicle and upto 10years old vehicle.
<li> Branches in Ramnad, Madurai, Coimbatore, Trichy & our head office in Chennai.
<li> A useful life of a vehicle in 15years and we fund their segments. We are proud for our last mile connectivity with the transport sector throughout &nbsp Tamilnadu with our loyal staff, committed service and best dedication.
<li> Attractive terms for the deposits and slnnire throughout our Chennai office with monthly quarterly and annual interest options.

        </ul>





<!-- NEWS RIGHT  -->


</div>
<!--part-1-->               
<!--part-2-->                
<!--part-2-->
<!--part-3-->
</div><!-- .container -->
<!--part-3-->

</section>
        <!-- CONTENT ENDS -->
       <!-- Div for styling purpose only -->
            <div class="blank_separator"></div>

            <!--prefooter-->
            <section>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <img src="img/shadow-divider.png" class="shadow_divider">
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row-fluid twitter_wrap">                        
                            <div class="span9" style="">
                              <p><a href=""style="color:#900;"> Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited,</a> A trusted financial service group in India.</a></p></div>
                            <style type="text/css">
                            .social:hover {opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=30);}
                            </style>



                    </div>
                </div>  
        </section>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <section>
        <footer style="height:230px;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <!-- Footer Widget 1 -->
                    <div class="span5">
                        <div class="textwidget"><p><a href="Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited.html"><img src="img/logo5.png"></a></p></br>
<p>A trusted financial service group in India. The activities of the group span savings products like Deposits, Car and Commercial Vehicle Finance...</p>
</div>
        </li>

                    </div>
  <style type="text/css"> 
  .quicklinks{ }
  </style>
                    <!-- Footer Widget 2 -->
                    <div class="span5" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                        <h3 class="widget_title">Quick Links</h3>
                        <ul id="quicklinks">
                        <li class="quicklinks"><a href="contactus.html">Branches</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"><a href="">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"> <a href="">Privacy policy</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"><a href="">Careers with us</a></li></ul></li>

                    </div>      

                    <div class="span5" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                        <h3 class="widget_title">Useful Links</h3>
                        <ul id="quicklinks">
                        <li class="quicklinks"><a href="download/Deposit Interest Rate.pdf">Deposit Rates</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"><a href="download/Deposit Application.pdf">Deposit Form</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"> <a href="download/Interest Rate Model.pdf">Interest Rate Model</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"> <a href="investment.html">Invester Relations</a></li>
                        <li class="quicklinks"><a href="download/Fair practice Code.pdf">Fair Practice Code</a></li></ul></li>

                    </div>  


                    <!-- Footer Widget 3 -->
                    <div class="span4 "style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
         <h3 class="widget_title">Head Office (Chennai)</h3>
        <p>
          No:110,5th floor,Prakash Presidium,<br />
          Mahatma Gandhi Road,<br />
          Nungabakkam,Chennai-600 034
          Phone:044-3022885</p>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <!-- footer 4-->


               <br>
             <div>
                    <img src="img/separator.png" alt="separator" />
                    <div class="span8"><p>Copyright 2014&copy;All Rights Reserved by Vijay Hemant Finance & Estates Limited.</p></div>
               </div>    

            </div><!-- /container -->
            </section>
        </footer>

    </div><!-- container-fluid ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share a link to the site so we can see what's going on it?

Comment: A few things: You should check your code. I think you are adding jQuery two times (one is version 1.5.2 and another 1.9.1), so they will conflict. Also, I can't find bootstrap's javascript file there, so probably that's why the menu is not working.

Answer (score 0):

On your meta tag for viewport, you need to add `initial-scale=1`. It should work without it, but you have disabled zooming on your code so it won't help.

Try using the Bootstrap CDN for JS and CSS. You are calling two CSS files and Bootstrap should only be one (not sure if one is the overrides?). Testing with the core files first before any overrides will help debug.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aibrean i tried your answer but wen i apply it the menu bar is becoming black. please help if there is any other solution.

Comment: Oh my bad...I didn't realize you are using deprecated Bootstrap. See updated answer

Comment: Also, I would remove `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` because you are also pulling in a more recent jQuery that is definitely supported by Bootstrap (1.5.2 is OLD).